# Tomcat in first request does not load page contents

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat8

So i have renamed tomcat lib folder by accident and than it have 404 error looking like this:
[Link to picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fONEd.png)

Than i restarted tomcat using `./catalina.sh stop`and `./catalina.sh start` once i restarted i do not see anymore similar messages but it gives sometimes page not found message which basically means 404 and it fails to load page content from first time i need manually press F5 and than it loads the page contents like design and etc but if i again press F5 it again gives same thing and i need to reload page again to see contents.

I have tried to run tomcat 8 by `./startup.sh`
Also have tried to change ports from 8080 to 80
Tried to run tomcat as non root user but i found out that i'm not root user on that user which i'm using anyways.

What I'm doing wrong?
I'm using Centos and tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem you need clean tomcat cache: delete work folder in tomcat folder.